# Building a simple timeline using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi I am using a sample timeline that was supplied on stack overflow. My problem is that the position of the elements that have the class name "event" will not stay on the timeline line once the page goes over the screen size. Does anyone know a way of having the events stay on the timeline when it goes over the screen size. I am limited to CSS and HTML. Thanks

```
<h2>Artist Timeline</h2>
        <div class="timeline">
            <div class="event up">
            <div class="detail">
                <h3>30 Mar 1853</h3>
                <p>Born in Groot-Zundert, the Netherlands</p>    
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="event down">
              <div class="detail">
                <h3>Jul 1869</h3>
                <p>Joins The Hague branch of the firm Goupil & Cie.</p>       
             </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
/* TIMELINE */

.timeline {
    height: 250px;
    margin: 1em;
    line-height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  .timeline:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    height: 26px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    background: white;
  }
  .event {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #7ed0df;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .detail {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: smaller;
  }
```

The pictures shows it working when on the screen size and what's happening when it goes over the screen size.
![Text]([image: What it looks like when it it is playing ball]
![Text][image: When it expands over the screen size it ends up below the timeline]

Comment: Could you add a little example which we can run? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example By ‘staying on the timeline’ are you meaning the white line isn’t seen?

Comment: ok will try to edit so its a runable example, yes the line is in a scroll bar but each even will not stay on the line once the screen size is surpassed.

Answer (score 0):

Having a bit of trouble understanding your question, but you could add the text-overflow property to you P tags. Creates a nice effect for overflow text.

```
.timeline p{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 230px;
}
```